# Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>

Tags: reactjs, html-select

I wrote the following code but with error:

index.js: 1 Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on `<select>` instead of setting `selected` on `<option>`.
I faced

```
<div className='form-group'>
  <label>Parent category</label>
  <select
    name='category'
    className='form-control'
    onChange={(e) => setParent(e.target.value)}
    defaultValue={parent}
  >
    <option>Please select</option>
    {categories.length > 0 &&
     categories.map((c) => (
       <option selected={c._id} key={c._id} value={c._id === parent}>
         {c.name}
       </option>
     ))}
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shubhaw has answer below, but what is your question about a "subcategory update section"? Can you provide more context/detail? Seems extracurricular to your question/issue here.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, in the subcategory update section, I can not display the category name and its subcategories, and it gives the above error when it also shows a loop mode, and both appear.

Comment: Well, all I can say at this point is: What sub-categories?, What do you mean "loop mode"? Both what? Seems we require a bit more context. Can you provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question?

Comment: Yes. Agreed to @DrewReese, please provide us more context and then I can update my answer according to that.

Answer (score 3):

You should not put `selected` property in the `option`. Rather use the `value` property of `select`.

And always follow this rule that either the component can be controlled or uncontrolled. If you are using a setter in onChange, then don't use `defaultValue`. Use the `value` property and set it with the state variable.

Your code should look something like this ([or find a working codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-sky-0pkv4?file=/src/App.js)):

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label>Parent category</label>
        <select
            name="category"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setParent(e.target.value)}
            value={parent}
        >
            <option>Please select</option>
            {categories.length > 0 &&
                categories.map((c) => (
                    <option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                        {c.name}
                      </option>
                ))
            }
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: There is a subcategory update section. I wanted them to be selected. What should I do?

Comment: I want to know in what format to get the categories and how to put in the option that the categories are displayed, of course, along with their sub.